# Python: JSON is not reading "&" character

Tags: python, json, flask, encoding

I am currently having this issue. When I add a query to the server (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:5000/?property=Ward&propertyValue=Ely%20North%20Ward, where Ward = Ely North Ward), the JSON returns values. However, if I wanted to filter Wards that contain the "&" character (e.g. Ward = Ely & Christchurch Ward), it does not return any values, just 
{
type: "FeatureCollection",
features: [ ]
}.

What can I do so that the function reads "&" characters, and returns the correct values from what I entered?

Code below:

````
from flask import Flask, escape, request 
import requests
import json 



def graphqlwfs(url):
    url = "https://osdatahubapi.os.uk/OSFeaturesAPI/wfs/v1?service=wfs&request=GetCapabilities"
    queryString = "&typenames=osfeatures:BoundaryLine_PollingDistrict&outputformat=geoJSON"


    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args


    if request_json and 'property' in request_json:
        property = request_json['property']
    elif request_args and 'property' in request_args:
        property = request_args['property']
    else:
        property = ""

    if request_json and 'propertyValue' in request_json:
        propertyValue = request_json['propertyValue']
    elif request_args and 'propertyValue' in request_args:
        propertyValue = request_args['propertyValue']
    else:
        propertyValue = ""


    filterString = "&filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>" + str(property) + "</PropertyName><Literal>" + str(propertyValue) + "</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>"

    if property == "":
        filterString = ""
    if propertyValue == "":
        filterString = ""


    newUrl = str(url.replace("GetCapabilities", "GetFeature") + queryString + filterString)
    response = requests.get(newUrl)

    features = response.json()



    return features


        ```
````

Comment: You might need to escape your ampersand in your URL.  Typically `&` has a special meaning in URLs, which might be why you are not seeing a return.  Simply replace it with `%26`

Comment: returns a json decode error

Comment: Is there anything I can do to stop it retuning the decode error?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the & character. In this case, the code for & is %26. So you can try

`?property=Ward&propertyValue=Ely%20%26%20Christchurch%20Ward`

For more information, read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) link.

Comment: returns the following error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score -1):

for me its working fine, may be i'am wrong tell me will change answer, may be needed more description.

```
a="sad& wasd"
if a=="sad& wasd":
   print("hi") 
output:hi
```

Comment: You aren't working with URLs or the `requests` library. The problem isn't with putting a `&` in a string.